# G++ execution Problem but compiles successfully

Tags: g++

Hello Friends,
              can anybody explain me what is the error in this procedure of compiling and executing a c++ program file.
[image]
[image: compiling and executing]

Comment: OFF TOPIC ... What terminal window are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't specified the name of the executable to produce with `-o NAME`, it will be called `a.out`, rather than the same name as the source file.

So either do:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program
./program
```

or

```
g++ program.cpp
./a.out
```

Comment: command for executing the a.out file?

Answer (score 0):

If you type
g++ progname.cpp

then it will create a file named a.out which will be the file you want to use in order to run the program.

But if you wanna make a file with the name you want then -

g++ -o   desiredname   progfile.cpp

now this will create a file with  whatever name you give
and run it using

./filename